# How to submit post data with ng2 file upload in angular 2?

Tags: angular, ng-file-upload

I am using ng2-file-upload in angular 2. Is there any way to submit my form data with file upload action?

Comment: Could you please give a more detailed explanation on what exactly you're wanting to do? I've worked with that package so I may be able to help, I'm just struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I am creating one user form using form builder. User form has firstname, lastname, email, profile_imag, status etc fields. How to post all of user input data (firstname, lastname, email etc...) with profile_image data using one server call.

I am using laravel as a backend,

Comment: If you look inside the example, they have `item.upload()`, that `item` has a property on it called `item.formData`, I THINK you can add your formdata on that via `item.formData=yourFormData`. I haven't used the package in this way.

Comment: @Ghanshyam Could you explain how to use ng2-file-upload with PHP? I trying to find something on internet, but nothing until now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have applied below methods for submit file upload data with form data (Posted answer: Jane Wayne)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was having the same problem using [ng2-file-upload](http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/). They have a hook called `onBeforeUploadItem`. The following did not work:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (fileItem: any) => {
  fileItem.formData.push( { someField: this.someValue } );
  fileItem.formData.push( { someField2: this.someValue2 } );
 };
}
```

When I logged out the content of `fileItem.formData` all the values are there. However, these form elements seem to never make it back to the server. I am using `Chrome` and when I observe the HTTP post, I saw the following:

Request Headers

```
POST /api/upload/csv HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 228
Origin: http://localhost:4200
x-access-token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyb290IiwiYWRkciI6IjA6MDowOjA6MDowOjA6MSIsInNjaGVtZSI6Imh0dHAiLCJwb3J0IjoiODA4MCIsImlhdCI6MTQ2OTUwMzM1NX0.jICVQdZD-6m705sZsaQJ5-51LztdIx9pAAKgVYgL3HRMMgrJh6ldFbYvUVtA_UQkSrvCrNJeWeo4C7QYe2W4Cw
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryCSUTihSBrgmwjxg1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/main
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.941072201.1467616449; token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyb290IiwiYWRkciI6IjA6MDowOjA6MDowOjA6MSIsInNjaGVtZSI6Imh0dHAiLCJwb3J0IjoiODA4MCIsImlhdCI6MTQ2OTUwMzM1NX0.jICVQdZD-6m705sZsaQJ5-51LztdIx9pAAKgVYgL3HRMMgrJh6ldFbYvUVtA_UQkSrvCrNJeWeo4C7QYe2W4Cw
```

Request Payload

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCSUTihSBrgmwjxg1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="data.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv


------WebKitFormBoundaryCSUTihSBrgmwjxg1--
```

---

### The actual solution

It turns out I was pretty close. The solution was to override `onBuildItemForm`.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.uploader.onBuildItemForm = (fileItem: any, form: any) => {
  form.append('someField', this.someValue); //note comma separating key and value
  form.append('someField2', this.someValue2);
 };
}
```

The instance `form` is of type [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). By looking at my HTTP post, I can see my form field values being sent to the server, and my server actually sees the values now.

Comment: When posting it this way, you are posting your 'someField' as multi-form-data so you won't be able to get it with req.body.  You'll have to use another package like multer to get at the value and then it will attach 'someField' as req.body.

Comment: @JaneWayne do you know how this would work if I would want to uploade multiple files and attach different information to all of them?

Comment: Just adding a detail that might trip some people up:

The form.append method is:

`form.append('key',value);`

*Note the comma separation between name & value, not colon.

Comment: @Jane Wayne, How to access those passed additional value in server side?

Comment: I have just used this portion of the logic inside a separate function which will be called on click of the upload button. Then trigger the upload. Something like this.. 'code' 

uploadMe(item) {
        this.uploader.onBuildItemForm = (fileItem: any, form: any) => {
            form.append('empid', '12345');
        };
        item.upload();
    }

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day ! :)

Answer (score 8):

```
this.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (item: FileItem) => {
  item.withCredentials = false;
  this.uploader.authToken = 'Bearer ' + this.boxTokenResponse.userToken;
  this.uploader.options.additionalParameter = {
    name: item.file.name,
    parent_id: this.parentFolderId
  };
};
```

This is how file-uploader.class.js pans the form data.

```
if (!this.options.disableMultipart) {
        sendable = new FormData();
        this._onBuildItemForm(item, sendable);
        sendable.append(item.alias, item._file, item.file.name);
        if (this.options.additionalParameter !== undefined) {
            Object.keys(this.options.additionalParameter).forEach(function (key) {
                sendable.append(key, _this.options.additionalParameter[key]);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to access those passed additional value in server side?

Comment: Generally on the server side you need to access the http request's header  object and look for specific header key and List of values.

Answer (score 0):

As for accessing the data in server, it can be done using `Multer`:

```
    const multer = require('multer');
    let DIR = './uploads/';

    let upload = multer({dest: DIR}).single('givenitemAlias');
        router.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
            console.log(req.body);//empty object
            upload(req, res, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    // An error occurred when uploading
                    return res.status(422).send("an Error occured")
                }
                // No error occured.
                console.log(req.body);//modified req.body with out key value pairs
                console.log(req.file);//metadata of the file
                return res.send("Upload Completed for "+temppathOfUploadedFile);
            });            
        });
```